# XCODE - Generate random numbers (between 1 and 16) and Outpout the result to different 16 UILAbels (no duplicate numbers)

Tags: random

Please can you Help me!

I Have this code for 16 UIlabels(label, label1, label2, label3)...

```
enter code here

>int randomText = rand() %16;
>switch (randomText) {
>   case 0:
>        label.text = @"1";
>        break;
>    case 1:
>        label.text = @"2";
>        break;
>    case 2:
>        label.text = @"3";
>        break;
>    case 3:
>        label.text = @"4";
>        break;
>    case 4:
>        label.text = @"5";
>        break;
>    ......\
```

We need IBACTION to generate a random numbers (exampple_range between 1 and 16) and Outpout the result to different 16 UILAbels in the project XCode and not repeat between labels and not repeat when start again.

-16 UILABELS with random numbers.
-No repeat number in a 16 UILAbels.

Example that we need (IBACTION) or Void:

```
>Label_1=5
>Label_2=9
>Label_3=2
>Label_4=14
>Label_5=1
>Label_6=15
>Label_7=16
>Label_8=3
>Label_9=4
>Label_10=6
>Label_11=12
>Label_12=8
>Label_13=13
>Label_14=9
>Label_15=16
>Label_16=15
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating random numbers, shuffle na array with the numbers/strings.

```
NSArray *vals = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16"];
NSUInteger count = [vals count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSInteger nElements = count - i;
    NSInteger n = arc4random_uniform(nElements) + i;
    [vals exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

Then, for each label, you set its value:

```
label.text = vals[index];
```

As an advise, set your labels to an array of their own, so after os shuffle the array you can easily set the values in a cycle.

```
NSUInteger vCount = [vals count];
NSUInteger lCount = [labels count];
NSUInteger count = MIN(vCount, lCount);
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    UILabel *lbl = labels[i];
    lbl.text = vals[i];
}
```

Hope it helps.